# How to suppress part of FAKE output?

Tags: f#, travis-ci, f#-fake, paket

I have a library that I build with FAKE, pack, and push to NuGet. Works fine.

Now, I want to do all that, including the "push" part, in continuous mode, via Travis CI. I know there are security concerns, but it seems that I can do this securely (at least in principle) by putting the NuGet API key in a Travis environment variable, so it's [not available to external pull requests](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/pull-requests/#Pull-Requests-and-Security-Restrictions), and pushing only when building a special dedicated branch.

The problem comes when FAKE meets Travis.

1. Turns out, when I use the [Paket.Push helper](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-paket.html), the whole `paket.exe` command line is emitted as FAKE's output, complete with my NuGet API key.
2. At the same time, it turns out that Travis lets any non-authenticated nosy individual to see full build logs of [any project](https://travis-ci.org/fscheck/FsCheck). With my NuGet API key right in there.

I know that I can disable the whole output from FAKE by redirecting it to `/dev/null` (in `.travis.yml`), but I'd like to keep *most* of the output, just hide that specific part with the key.

I could not find any relevant parameters in the [`PaketPushParams` structure](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/master/src/app/FakeLib/PaketHelper.fs#L46), and Google didn't turn up anything either. The next step would be to look through FAKE source code to see if the output is even conditional, but I thought I'd ask first. I can't be the first person to hit this. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find an answer with Google either, but I did know more or less where to look in the FAKE source code, so I went ahead and did that.

It looks like the [Paket.Push helper calls `ExecProcess`](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/dab7b5aea40c0855cf35fc7d6e67fa4f411fb24b/src/app/FakeLib/PaketHelper.fs#L152-152) to actually run the relevant task. `ExecProcess` eventually calls `ExecProcessWithLambdas` to do the work, and the line in `ExecProcessWithLambdas` that prints the process name and arguments out to the FAKE log [checks the `enableProcessTracing` variable first](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/fd6a04ef2b6c20ad94e15720279f93061186c3e5/src/app/FakeLib/ProcessHelper.fs#L83-L84), and will not output the process name and arguments if that variable is false. The `enableProcessTracing` variable is [undocumented, but mutable](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/fd6a04ef2b6c20ad94e15720279f93061186c3e5/src/app/FakeLib/ProcessHelper.fs#L35-L36) so you should be able to set it. I have not tried this myself yet, but in principle you should be able to do:

```
ProcessHelper.enableProcessTracing <- false // Logging off
// Do security-sensitive work here
ProcessHelper.enableProcessTracing <- true  // Logging back on for rest of build
```

Does that do what you need?